# Cannot create team foundation 2012 project?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I restored the tfs 2012 with an old backup after a new installation, every thing works just fine but cannot create new project thanks to the following error that i think a wrong credentials info somewhere in TFS or ReportServer databases, it doesn't match the new Report credentials.

Does anybody know where to change these info ?

```
   http://abc:7979/ReportServer -> ok 
   http://abc:7979/Reports -> ok



> Module: Engine Event Description: TF30162: Task "Populate Reports"
> from Group "Reporting" failed Exception Type:
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.PcwException Exception Message: The
> Project Creation Wizard encountered an error while creating reports to
> the SQL Server Reporting Services on
> http://server:7979/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx. Exception
> Details: The Project Creation Wizard encountered a problem while 
> creating reports on the SQL Server Reporting Services on
> http://server:7979/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx.  The reason
> for the failure cannot be determined at this time.  Because the
> operation failed, the wizard was not able to finish  creating the SQL
> Server Reporting Services site. Stack Trace:    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.RosettaReportUploader.Execute(ProjectCreationContext
> context, XmlNode taskXml)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.ProjectCreationEngine.TaskExecutor.PerformTask(IProjectComponentCreator
> componentCreator, ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml)   
> at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.ProjectCreationEngine.RunTask(Object
> taskObj)
> --   Inner Exception   -- Exception Message: TF30225: Error uploading report 'Backlog Overview':
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The current action cannot
> be completed. The user data source credentials do not meet the
> requirements to run this report or shared dataset. Either the user
> data source credentials are not stored in the report server database,
> or the user data source is configured not to require credentials but
> the unattended execution account is not specified. --->
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InvalidDataSourceCredentialSettingException:
> The current action cannot be completed. The user data source
> credentials do not meet the requirements to run this report or shared
> dataset. Either the user data source credentials are not stored in the
> report server database, or the user data source is configured not to
> require credentials but the unattended execution account is not
> specified.    at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2005Impl.SetCacheOptions(String
> Report, Boolean CacheReport, ExpirationDefinition Expiration, Guid
> batchId)    at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005.SetCacheOptions(String
> Report, Boolean CacheReport, ExpirationDefinition Expiration) (type
> ReportingUploaderException) Exception Stack Trace:    at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Reporting.ReportingUploader.UploadReport(XmlNode
> report)    at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Reporting.ReportingUploader.HandleCreateReports(XmlNode
> node)    at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Reporting.ReportingUploader.Run()   
> at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.RosettaReportUploader.Execute(ProjectCreationContext
> context, XmlNode taskXml)
> 
> Inner Exception Details:
> 
> Exception Message: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The
> current action cannot be completed. The user data source credentials
> do not meet the requirements to run this report or shared dataset.
> Either the user data source credentials are not stored in the report
> server database, or the user data source is configured not to require
> credentials but the unattended execution account is not specified.
> ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InvalidDataSourceCredentialSettingException:
> The current action cannot be completed. The user data source
> credentials do not meet the requirements to run this report or shared
> dataset. Either the user data source credentials are not stored in the
> report server database, or the user data source is configured not to
> require credentials but the unattended execution account is not
> specified.    at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2005Impl.SetCacheOptions(String
> Report, Boolean CacheReport, ExpirationDefinition Expiration, Guid
> batchId)    at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005.SetCacheOptions(String
> Report, Boolean CacheReport, ExpirationDefinition Expiration) (type
> SoapException)SoapException Details: <detail><ErrorCode
> xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">rsInvalidDataSourceCredentialSetting</ErrorCode><HttpStatus
> xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">400</HttpStatus><Message
> xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">The current
> action cannot be completed. The user data source credentials do not
> meet the requirements to run this report or shared dataset. Either the
> user data source credentials are not stored in the report server
> database, or the user data source is configured not to require
> credentials but the unattended execution account is not
> specified.</Message><HelpLink
> xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&amp;EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&amp;EvtID=rsInvalidDataSourceCredentialSetting&amp;ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&amp;ProdVer=11.0.2100.60</HelpLink><ProductName
> xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">Microsoft SQL
> Server Reporting Services</ProductName><ProductVersion
> xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">11.0.2100.60</ProductVersion><ProductLocaleId
> xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">127</ProductLocaleId><OperatingSystem
> xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">OsIndependent</OperatingSystem><CountryLocaleId
> xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">1033</CountryLocaleId><MoreInformation
> xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices"><Source>ReportingServicesLibrary</Source><Message
> msrs:ErrorCode="rsInvalidDataSourceCredentialSetting"
> msrs:HelpLink="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&amp;EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&amp;EvtID=rsInvalidDataSourceCredentialSetting&amp;ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&amp;ProdVer=11.0.2100.60"
> xmlns:msrs="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">The
> current action cannot be completed. The user data source credentials
> do not meet the requirements to run this report or shared dataset.
> Either the user data source credentials are not stored in the report
> server database, or the user data source is configured not to require
> credentials but the unattended execution account is not
> specified.</Message></MoreInformation><Warnings
> xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices" /></detail>
> Exception Stack Trace:    at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.HandleReply(TfsClientOperation
> operation, TfsMessage message, Object[]& outputs)    at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation
> operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs)  
> at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Reporting.ReportingService.Invoke(TfsClientOperation
> operation, Object[] outputs)    at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Reporting.ReportingService.SetCacheOptions(String
> Report, Boolean CacheReport, ExpirationDefinition Expiration)    at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Reporting.ReportingUploader.UploadReport(XmlNode
> report)
```

UPDATE: i fixed it

When you open http:///Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx, you may find the datasource Tfs2010OlapReportDS and Tfs2010ReportDS, open the datasource, make sure that the datasource are using  Credentials stored securely in the report server and Use as Windows credentials when connecting to the data source is checked.

Last time I used Windows Integrated security, so the web service might not be able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about 2012 version but this kind of info in 2010 version is set Team Foundation Administration Console.  Give it a try – it shouldn’t be much different in 2012 version.

[image]